# Is there a way to automatically upgrade DBeaver?

Tags: fedora, software-installation, applications-database

I am trying to update DBeaver Community Edition 7.0.3 to (currently) newest 7.1.0 edition on Fedora 30. When I start DBeaver a "Version Update" window pops up with buttons as options to *Upgrade* and *Details* (manually download installation file). When I click on *Upgrade* it freezes window and program crashes.

Is there any way to upgrade it AUTOMATICALLY without loosing any setup (DB connections, themes, etc.) or package MUST be manually replaced?